# How to change log level of org.hibernate.SQL to info form dubug?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am not native.

I have known that underline property prints out Sql querys

application.properteis

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

print out logs

```
2021-12-31 16:43:30.927 DEBUG 3664 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT * FROM Member
```

But I want to **print out info level**.I tried this, But this didn't print out any logs

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=info
```

How to change log level to info? I want to make this
print out logs

```
2021-12-31 16:43:30.927 INFO 3664 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT * FROM Member
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the log level of a log statement because the code defines on what level it will log.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can i custormize for that?

Comment: No. Hibernate is using the default level.